# Is there a way in WordPress elementor, astra for forms to validate one of its fields' data exists in a table?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, forms, elementor

I'm trying to make a custom registration form for users table which has a field called 'sponsor user id', which should be able to check if the id inputted in the field exists in the users table. I have no idea on how to get around it. I'm trying out forminator but there's no option to add manual sql, or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you will probably be searching the same problem that I was facing.
I was basically trying to verify the file number whether it exists in the Database or not if it exists it gives a success message, if not then it shows invalid number. My Tab in DB contained only one col i.e fileNumber. I was trying to validate it using elementor form. But there were many problems.
so I used the HTML code in elementor and there I put the following form

```
<form role="form1" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group1">
  <input id="filenumber1" name="filenumber1" type="text" placeholder="File
       Number" class="form-control1 input-sm1" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block1" 
     name="submitbtn1">
   </div>
   </form>
```

then I put the following PHP code snippet into my WordPress theme’s functions.php file. functions.php file is located within your WordPress admin dashboard > Appearance > Theme Editor.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn1'])){
    global $wpdb;
    
    $search_value = $_POST['filenumber1'];

    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT fileNumber FROM wp_filenumberinsert WHERE fileNumber LIKE '%$search_value%'");

    if($result==true){
        echo "<script>alert('your file is approved');</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('your file is not approved please contact customer center');</script>";

    }
    
}
```

and boom! it worked:-D